# class-transformer additional transform decorators not being applied in Nestjs controller with ClassSerializerInterceptor

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-transformer

I am writing a test for a nestjs application but the additional transform decorators set on the `Entity` class are being ignored. However, they are applied when using `instanceToPlain`.

```
import { Exclude, Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class UserEntity {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.toISOString())
  createdAt: Date;
  @Exclude()
  updatedAt: Date;

  constructor(partial: Partial<UserEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
@UseGuards(FirebaseAuthGuard)
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(
    @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserPostDto,
    @CurUser() user: DecodedIdToken
  ): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return await this.usersService.create({
      ...createUserDto,
      id: user.uid,
      emailAddress: user.email,
    });
  }
}
```

This is the mock generator:

```
export function createMockUser(data: Partial<User>): User {
  return {
    id: data.id || randomUUID(),
    firstName: data.firstName || faker.name.firstName(),
    lastName: data.lastName || faker.name.lastName(),
    emailAddress: data.emailAddress || faker.internet.email(),
    createdAt: data.createdAt || new Date(),
    updatedAt: data.updatedAt || new Date(),
  };
}
```

This is the test:

```
  describe('create', () => {
    it('creates and returns user', async () => {
      const randomUser = createMockUser({});

      const user = new UserEntity(randomUser);
      usersServiceCreateMock.mockResolvedValue(user);

      const response = await tester.http
        .post('/api/users')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer fake-token')
        .send({
          firstName: randomUser.firstName,
          lastName: randomUser.lastName,
        })
        .expect(201);

        expect(response.body).toEqual(instanceToPlain(user));
     });
  });
```

This is the output:

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 2

      Object {
    -   "createdAt": "2022-08-21T14:10:03.879Z",
    +   "createdAt": "2022-08-21T14:10:03.943Z",
        "emailAddress": "Jamison.Kunde@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Ayana",
        "id": "f9215a97-ead5-4521-8cee-f7b585afa131",
        "lastName": "Oberbrunner",
    +   "updatedAt": "2022-08-21T14:10:03.944Z",
      }
```

As you can see the transforms are correctly applied to the expected value but are not applied in the output. I have confirmed through debugging that in both instances the `class-transformer` is involved.

Comment: What does `this.usersService.create()` return? Is it an instance of a `UserEntity` or something that _looks_ like a `UserEntity`?

Comment: correct, see the spy implementation in the test.

Comment: I guess you are not using the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` in your test.

Comment: How so? It's applied to the controller that I am testing.